# list files whose name meets 3 different criteria

Tags: linux, debian, bash

Is it possible to achieve the following with a simple `ls` command using bash.
List all the files that begin with two letters, have an `e` in the name and end with `1` or more letter.
If so, what is the command and does extended globbing need to be enabled ?

Comment: `ls [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*e*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]`. No. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: ooops - mine was ls [a-z][a-z]*e**[!0-9]

Comment: i have tried your command but it will not list a filename that has an e if it is either of the last two characters. example - it will list a filename if it is bakers, but it will not list banker because the e is the second last characater( i think )

Comment: Made a mistake. `ls [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*e*[a-zA-Z]` should also list "banker".

Comment: Is find with two regexs not an option? so something like find . -maxdepth 1 -regex ^.*e.*$ -regex ^[.][/][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]$

Comment: Similar: [How to open or list all files whose name matches two patterns in Bash](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/287070)

Answer (score 5):

`ls` doesn't match file names (unless you want to consider GNU extensions like `--include`/`--exclude`). It's the shell globs that are typically used for that.

```
ls -ld [[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]*e*[[:alpha:]]
```

would find files that match those requirements, but would miss `ee` for instance. You could do:

#### zsh

Using the *AND NOT*/*EXCEPT* operator (`~`) and *NOT* (`^`):

```
setopt extendedglob
ls -ld [[:alpha:]](#c2)*~^*e*~^*[[:alpha:]]
```

Or using `perl`-like look ahead regular expression operators:

```
setopt rematchpcre
match() [[ $REPLY =~ '^(?=.*e)(?=.*[[:alpha:]]$)[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]' ]]
ls -ld *(+match)
```

#### ksh93

Using `&` inside `@(...)`:

```
ls -ld @([[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]*&*e*&*[[:alpha:]])
```

Same with its *augmented* regexps (enabled with `~(X:...)`):

```
ls -ld ~(X:[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]].*&.*e.*&.*[[:alpha:]])
```

Or using perl-like look-ahead operators:

```
ls -ld ~(P:(?=.*e)(?=.*[[:alpha:]]$)[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]])*
```

#### bash

`bash` has no *AND* operator but it does support a subset of `ksh`'s operators when the `extglob` option is enabled, so you could do things like:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -ld @([[:alpha:]]?([[:alpha:]]*)e?(*[[:alpha:]])|e[[:alpha:]]?(*[[:alpha:]]))
```

`@(x|y)` (like `zsh`'s `(x|y)`) is a *OR* operator. `?(x)` is an optional `x` (like `zsh`'s `(x|)`; `@(x|)` would also work for that in `ksh`/`bash`).

Another trick is to use the fact that *"A and B"* is *"not(not(A) or not(B))"*, and the subset of ksh globs supported by `bash` so happens to include a *not* and *or* operators so you can do:

```
ls -ld !(!([[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]*)|!(*e*)|!(*[[:alpha:]]))
```

Those ones would also work in `ksh` (all variants, no `shopt` there) where those operators come from in the first place.

#### Non-glob-based approaches

With `find`:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -name '[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]*' \
                        -name '*e*' \
                        -name '*[[:alpha:]]' -exec ls -ld {} +
```

(beware the file list won't be sorted and file names containing bytes that don't form valid characters will be excluded; file names will also be prefixed with `./`).

Comment: just trying that command now and it doesnt appear to work ?

Comment: @damiant, which command? In which shell? And in which way does it not work?

Comment: the bash command. i was trying with ls | grep “^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z].*e.*[a-zA-Z]$” but that wont work if either of the first 2 characters are e

Comment: @damiant what file name does that `ls -ld @([[:alpha:]]?([[:alpha:]]*)e?(*[[:alpha:]])|e[[:alpha:]]?(*[[:alpha:]]))` `bash` command fail to match or fail to not-match. For me it correctly matches `ee`, `eea`, `ee1a` and correctly fails  to match `ee1`, `eee1` and `ee11`